# Django: Facebook Connect Oauth2 Permissions

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

In my Django project, I have set up [pyfacebook](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) & [django-facebookconnect](http://code.google.com/p/django-facebookconnect/) to let the user login with their Fb account. However I now need to get the right [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) to get the user's data & save it in my db.

**How do you add the permissions to pyfacebook & django-facebookconnect?**

In facebook.**init**.py there is this function which I think is where I need to change the scope somehow.

Thanks for the help!

```
   def get_login_url(self, next=None, popup=False, canvas=True,
                      required_permissions=None):
        """
        Returns the URL that the user should be redirected to in order to login.

        next -- the URL that Facebook should redirect to after login
        required_permissions -- permission required by the application

        """
        if self.oauth2:
            args = {
                'client_id': self.app_id,
                'redirect_uri': next,
            }

            if required_permissions:
                args['scope'] = required_permissions

            if popup:
                args['display'] = 'popup'

            return self.get_graph_url('oauth/authorize', **args)
        else:
            args = {'api_key': self.api_key, 'v': '1.0'}

            if next is not None:
                args['next'] = next

            if canvas is True:
                args['canvas'] = 1

            if popup is True:
                args['popup'] = 1

            if required_permissions:
                args['req_perms'] = ",".join(required_permissions)

            if self.auth_token is not None:
                args['auth_token'] = self.auth_token

            return self.get_url('login', **args)
```

---

Update:

When you click the connect button, it passes facebookConnect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function() {FB.Facebook.init("{{ facebook_api_key }}", "{% url facebook_xd_receiver %}")});

    function facebookConnect(loginForm) {
        FB.Connect.requireSession();
        FB.Facebook.get_sessionState().waitUntilReady(function(){loginForm.submit();});
    }
    function pushToFacebookFeed(data){
        if(data['success']){
            var template_data = data['template_data'];
            var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
            feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){});
        } else {
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    }
    function pushToFacebookFeedAndRedirect(data){
        if(data['success']){
            var template_data = data['template_data'];
            var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
            feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){window.location.href=template_data['url'];});
        } else {
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    }
    function pushToFacebookFeedAndReload(data){
        if(data['success']){
            var template_data = data['template_data'];
            var template_bundle_id = data['template_bundle_id'];
            feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,function(){window.location.reload();});
        } else {
            alert(data['errors']);
        }
    }
    function feedTheFacebook(template_data,template_bundle_id,callback) {
        FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(
            template_bundle_id,
            template_data,
            null, null, null,
            FB.RequireConnect.promptConnect,
            callback
        );
    }
</script>
```

xd_receiver calls:

```
 <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.debug.js" type="text/javascript">
</script
```

Comment: So, you pass in some stuff for required_permissions when you call this function, and what does the resultant URL look like? (Please comment out oauth keys when you post it, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I switched over to the django [socialregistration](https://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration) module & that worked great.