# Django SocialRegistration won't connect to FB.login()

Tags: javascript, django, facebook, oauth-2.0

After [two days of fighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053080/django-facebook-connect-oath2-permissions) with FB Connect, I have integrated Socialregistration into my project, but when I click on the Facebook connect button, nothing happens. The weirdest part is that it connected once- but it hasn't since.

Onclick calls facebookConnect, and the FB.login breaks at the handleResponse (the second alert doesn't pop up). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<div id="fb-root">
    {% if is_https %}<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>{% else %}<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>{% endif %}
</div>
<script>
  // initialize the library with the API key
  FB.init({ apiKey: '{{ facebook_api_key }}', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  function facebookConnect(form){
        alert('testsss');
        function handleResponse(response){
                    alert('test2');
          form.submit();
      }
      FB.login(handleResponse,{perms:'publish_stream,sms,offline_access,email,read_stream,status_update'});
  }


</script>


{% load socialregistration_tags %}
{% comment %}
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"></fb:login-button>
{% endcomment %}

<form class="connect-button" name="login" method="post" action="{% if logged_in %}{% url facebook_connect %}{% else %}{% url facebook_login %}{% endif %}">
{% social_csrf_token %}
{% if next %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
{% endif %}
<input type="image" onclick="alert('tests'); facebookConnect(this.form);return false;" src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/fbconnect/login-buttons/connect_light_large_long.gif" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was I had the Fb JS files listed twice - once in my base.html & once on the page being loaded. Lesson - list the JS file only once.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO using FB Connect from JavaScript is very tricky to do properly, especially when you need to post status updates to FB etc. This is because it's too easy to get into the situation in which there is no correlation between user on your site and user logged to FB.

That's why personally I tend to use redirect-based oauth and to use FB Graph API from the backend, where I can make sure that everything is ok.